# Numbered range variables with character type

Tags: sas

I have an INPUT statement that reads similar to this:

```
INPUT FOO BAR CHR1 $ CHR2 $ CHR3 $ CHR4 $ CHR5 $ BLAH;
```

`CHR1` to `CHR5` are all character variables (not numeric). If they were numeric, I could simplify it using a numbered range to `CHR-CHR5` but because they are character variables, I don't know how to shorten the `INPUT` command. I tried this:

```
INPUT FOO BAR CHR1-CHR5 $ BLAH;
```

But it tries to read them as numeric variables, not as character variables, which results in incorrect data loading.

How can I import a range of character variables and assign them consecutive names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INPUT FOO BAR (CHR1-CHR5)($) BLAH;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an array with the input (below is a comma delimited infile example):

```
data databases;
    infile datalines DSD;
    array databases(1:5) $15 CHR1-CHR5;
    input databases(*);

    datalines;
    Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, DB2
;
run;
```